# How to compress html pages using SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

Tags: .htaccess, mod-deflate

I am not able to get compressed html pages in my browser even though I am 100% sure mod_deflate is activated on my server.

My htaccess file has this code snippet :

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
   <Files *.html>
   SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
   </Files>
</IfModule>
```

A non compressed excerpt of my content is:

```
<div>
   <div>
   Content
   </div>
</div>
```

With the htaccess code I am using, I would expect to get the output below in my browser (no space and no tabs at the beginning of each line):

```
<div>
<div>
Content
</div>
</div>
```

Is there something wrong with the code I am using in the htaccess file?

Is keeping all tabs in front of each html line after compression the normal behavior of mod_deflate? 
If so, would you recommend that I switch tabs with spaces in my html code to get the desired effect?

Thanks for your insights on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Deflate output filter to compress the content

1. Your content should be at least 120 bytes; compressing lesser bytes increases the output size.
2. The http client making the request should support `gzip`/`deflate` encoding.

Most modern Web browsers support gzip encoding and automatically decompress the gziped content for you. So what you are seeing using a Web browser's *View Page Source* option is not the compressed content. To verify if your browser received a compressed content, hit the F12 Key, select the Network tab and your requested page. If the response header has `Content-Encoding: gzip`, you can be sure the compression worked.

In Firefox, you can remove support for gzip,deflate by going to `about:config` and emptying the value for `network.http.accept-encoding`. Now with no support for gzip, Firefox will  receive uncompressed content from your Apache server.

Alternatively, if you want to see the compressed content, you can use a client that does not automatically decompress the contents for you (unless you use `--compressed` option).

You can use `curl` for this:

```
curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" http://example.com/page.html > page.gz
```

Comment: Gzip is in the response header. That would mean the compression works. However, when I submit the page on Google PageSpeed Insights, it keeps telling me I should minify html resources. I don't understand how the html page could not already be minified if the compression does work in Apache. That does not make sense to me. Thank you.

Comment: It means you can simplify your html; remove unnecessary tags etc.

Comment: The reco is really about minifying the page and removing spaces, tabs etc. https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources

Comment: Totally makes sense now after reading the gzip-versus minify link. Many thanks.